# Reason behind "search" endpoint url naming

Tags: jhipster

I was curious - what is the reason behind using an underscore in the `_search` endpoints ?

Comment: [The underscore is inherited from ElasticSearch](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-elasticsearch/)'s REST web-service API which also uses underscores - so your question should be asking why ElasticSearch uses underscores.

Comment: you might as well tell me why elastic uses underscores so ?